# Verilog simulation output is wrong, binary to Gray converter

Tags: verilog

I am designing a binary to Gray code converter. This is my main code:

```
module gray_code (bin_num, Gray_num);

input [3:0] bin_num; //binary input
output [3:0] Gray_num; //gray output


assign Gray_num[3] = bin_num[3];
assign Gray_num[2] = bin_num[3]^bin_num[2];
assign Gray_num[1] = bin_num[2]^bin_num[1];
assign Gray_num[0] = bin_num[1]^bin_num[0]; 

endmodule
```

And this is testbench:

```
module gray_code_tb;

reg [3:0] bin_num;
wire [3:0] Gray_num;    
integer i;

gray_code DUT(.bin_num(bin_num),.Gray_num(Gray_num));

initial begin

for(i=0;i<16;i=i+1)begin
    bin_num=i;
    $display("BIN = %b   GRAY =%b", bin_num, Gray_num);
end
end

endmodule
```

The output I get after simulation is:

```
BIN = 0000   GRAY =xxxx;
BIN = 0001   GRAY =xxxx;
BIN = 0010   GRAY =xxxx;
BIN = 0011   GRAY =xxxx;
```

Why is it showing all x for Gray code?

Answer (score 2):

In your simulation no time elapses. So the signals never have the opportunity to change.

Add a `#100;` after `bin_num=i;`